# Show the column header to a row if there is value in cells of that columns without VBA

Tags: excel

Update 1:

Because my question is not clear, so I post second example

[image: Example 2]

Because row 2, there is value 1 at Item 04 so the Get Item Name = Item 04. It is random and have a large number of columns (500).

The problem:

I would like to have a way to get a column header if there is any value input to the cells under that header.  Please note that if at row 2 and column 1 has value, then other cell of row 2 will not have any value (other than 0).

It is hard to explain the problem in words so I have created an example.

[image: Sample]

Comment: so you want the yellow "Column 1" to appear only if in the same row a green cell has a value? If so, why does table 2 not show any header? Anyway, try this formula, say in header cell C3: `=IF(COUNTA($D4:$F4)>0,"Column 1","")`

Comment: Because in column 1 has 2 cells cell 2 and cell 3 have value>0, so the header show column 1 on row 2 and 3

Comment: I think you mix up column and row header?  To me, the yellow "Column 1" is a _row header_, the white one a _column header_!

Comment: Ahhhh - could it be that with `1`, `2` and `3` you always refer to the _same_ table at different steps in the process? i.e. 1=the blank table 2=the input from the user 3=the result of the calculated headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I posted a formula in the comments above, you may not have seen it. This is it:

`=IF(COUNTA($B2:$D2)=0,"",INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B2:$D2<>"",0),0)))`

that will get the header for the first instance of a populated cell - if you have numeric values and want to ignore zeroes change to

`=IF(COUNTA($B2:$D2)=0,"",INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B2:$D2>0,0),0)))`

Either way the formula can be extended to as large a range as you need

.....and if you have 500 columns you could use IFERROR to shorten a little

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B2:$D2>0,0),0)),"")`

Comment: Why would you use `INDEX($B2:$D2<>"",0)` instead of simply `$B2:$D2<>""`?

Comment: Wow - this hack is new to me! Brilliant! Can't add enough +1! :-)

Comment: Barry, is there a way to expand your IFERROR (for many columns) to have more than one header represented, eg if there's a 1 in a few columns, you'd have "Column 1, Column 3, Column XX" rather than just the first hit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for a particular table which is relative small table with countable number of columns (i.e 3)  try this

```
=IF(COUNTA(G8)>0,"Column 1",IF(COUNTA(H8)>0,"Column 2",IF(COUNTA(I8)>0,"Column 3",""))).
```

my question is what if you have table contain 20 or 100 columns?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say *"column header"* you really mean *"row header"*.

Considering that the first cell (containing the text `"Column Header"`) is at `A1` this is the formula you have to introduce in cell `A2`:

```
=IF(B2>0, $B$1, IF(C2>0, $C$1, IF(D2>0, $D$1, "")))
```

Drag this formula down on as many rows as you need and it'll (hopefully) achieve what you want.

Comment: I updated with second example.  Basically, I would like to cell the header of above the cells that contains any value greater than 0.  The point is each row will only contains one cell with value, others cells are all zero.

Comment: @NCC OK, I think this formula does what you want. Have you tried it?

Comment: for 500 columns as stated in revised question that won't be a very practical approach - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a solution with more than 3 columns, this formula will return you the right header.

I assume that you data starts in row 2, column B - and row 1 contains the column headers.

Use this formula in B1 and copy it down:

```
=IF(COUNTA($B2:$D2)=0,"",INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISBLANK($B2:$D2),0),0)))
```

If your data extends further than column D, simply change this in the formula.

Comment: ....but * won't work with numeric values try `=IF(COUNTA($B2:$D2)=0,"",INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B2:$D2<>"",0),0)))` to accommodate 1s as per example...or any text or number values

Comment: @barryhoudini: thanks for pointing this out. I update it (using your INDEX trick)...