# Show the column header to a row if there is a certain value in cells of that columns

Tags: excel

There's a certain [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076300/show-the-column-header-to-a-row-if-there-is-value-in-cells-of-that-columns-witho) which guided me here and seemed to be the solution to what I was searching.

In my case the value in the cells is either N or Y (no empty cells/non numeric). And i want a formula that searches in the different columns to find the Y value so it returns that headername in the cell.(see image - result is Column A (Only one Y per line)
[Snip of excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHOTK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the Y in the current row using MATCH and find the corresponding cell in the header row using INDEX:-

=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,MATCH("Y",$B2:$G2,0))