# Show the column header to a row if there is value in cells of that column

Tags: excel

My question is similar to the following one already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076300/show-the-column-header-to-a-row-if-there-is-value-in-cells-of-that-columns-witho).

The only difference is that I need to merge all rows that have the value 1 and ignore all 0 values.

So if my table looks like this...

[image]

I need another column that will look as so...

```
Result

N/A
N/A
ArticleList pii, ArticleList medline
ArticleList pii
...
```

I tried using the following...

```
=IF(COUNTA($B2:$D2)=0,"",INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B2:$D2>0,0),0)))
```

...I also tried changing the `0` to a `1`, but I'm still getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the table starts at A1...

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(A2=1,$A$1,""),IF(B2=1,$B$1,""))
```

afterwards you can manipulate as you see fit to add commas and/or spaces.

[image]